# Get start and end date from a list of date ranges

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array of object which have date ranges from two fields.

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(12) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "19"
    ["date_start"]=>
    string(19) "2018-01-15 00:00:00"
    ["date_end"]=>
    string(19) "2018-01-16 00:00:00"
    ["promo_name"]=>
    string(19) "Promo 1"

  }
  [1]=>
  array(12) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(2) "18"
    ["date_start"]=>
    string(19) "2018-01-16 00:00:00"
    ["date_end"]=>
    string(19) "2018-01-19 00:00:00"
    ["promo_name"]=>
    string(34) "Promo 2"

  }
}
```

I want to find the first date_start and last date_end from a list of arrays. From those two values, I then want to use DatePeroid so I can get another list of dates by day between those two values.

```
    function sortFunction( $a, $b ) {
        return strtotime($a["date_start"]) - strtotime($b["date_start"]);
    }
    usort($query, "sortFunction");
```

I've sorted them at the moment by date_start but that won't complete the logic to get the last end date.

Not sure how the best way to proceed it.

Comment: Loop through the array once, keep track of the highest and lowest dates you've found so far, check with each entry whether its dates are higher/lower and replace your highest/lowest dates accordingly. Can be made into an `array_reduce`.

Comment: Thanks! Will give this a go.

Comment: I am struggling to remove them using array_reduce, do you have an example of how it would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example using an array reduction:

```
$result = array_reduce($query, function ($a, $i) {
    if (strtotime($i['date_start']) < strtotime($a['date_start'])) {
        $a['date_start'] = $i['date_start'];
    }

    if (strtotime($i['date_end']) > strtotime($a['date_end'])) {
        $a['date_end'] = $i['date_end'];
    }

    return $a;
}, $query[0]);

echo $result['date_start'], ' - ', $result['date_end'];
```

Comment: I tried a way which would have worked but yours is much much more concise code! Thanks so much for your help :)